# Script to find webmaster contact details

Tags: ruby, search, scripting, information-extraction

As part of a summer project I am currently undertaking, I am interested in writing a script to automate the retrieval of the contact email address for a particular site's webmaster. Is there any information anyone can direct my way to start me off? Stuff like research papers, source code for similar applications etc. I am currently reading "Introduction to Information Retrieval" by Manning, Raghavan and Schutz, as this work is part of a larger information extraction project, in which I eventually hope to develop a people search system. Oh yes, and I intend to write these systems in Ruby, if that is any further help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Simone Carletti's pure ruby [`whois client & parser`](https://github.com/weppos/whois) GitHub project. Here's a usage example:

```
r = Whois.whois("google.com")
# => #<Whois::Record>

t = r.technical_contact
# => #<Whois::Record::Contact>

t.email
# => "dns-admin@google.com"
```

Comment: This is a brilliant starting point - one of the options I wanted to look into was using whois searches. Had heard about the whois technology before but was unsuccessful in using it to find webmaster email addresses. Thanks